# emscripten complex function set to zero

Tags: c++, emscripten

I'm trying to cross compile some code and I have this line that is giving an error and I don't know what it is supposed to do so I can fix it.

typedef std::complex< double > COMPLEX;

COMPLEX* _matrix[MATRIX_NODES+OFFSET];  // For tran, real is now, imag is saved.

_matrix[ii][jj].real() = 0;

I'm not sure what the =0 is supposed to do. It compiles with clang and g++ but not emscripten.
There is a different complex number library for emscripten.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the definition in emscripten which is different from the regular library.

```
template<>
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY complex<double>
{
double __re_;
double __im_;
public:
typedef double value_type;

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR complex(double __re = 0.0, double __im = 0.0)
    : __re_(__re), __im_(__im) {}
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR complex(const complex<float>& __c);
explicit _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR complex(const complex<long double>& __c);

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR double real() const {return __re_;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR double imag() const {return __im_;}

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void real(value_type __re) {__re_ = __re;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void imag(value_type __im) {__im_ = __im;}

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator= (double __re)
    {__re_ = __re; __im_ = value_type(); return *this;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator+=(double __re) {__re_ += __re; return *this;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator-=(double __re) {__re_ -= __re; return *this;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator*=(double __re) {__re_ *= __re; __im_ *= __re; return *this;}
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator/=(double __re) {__re_ /= __re; __im_ /= __re; return *this;}

template<class _Xp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator= (const complex<_Xp>& __c)
    {
        __re_ = __c.real();
        __im_ = __c.imag();
        return *this;
    }
template<class _Xp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator+=(const complex<_Xp>& __c)
    {
        __re_ += __c.real();
        __im_ += __c.imag();
        return *this;
    }
template<class _Xp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator-=(const complex<_Xp>& __c)
    {
        __re_ -= __c.real();
        __im_ -= __c.imag();
        return *this;
    }
template<class _Xp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator*=(const complex<_Xp>& __c)
    {
        *this = *this * complex(__c.real(), __c.imag());
        return *this;
    }
template<class _Xp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY complex& operator/=(const complex<_Xp>& __c)
    {
        *this = *this / complex(__c.real(), __c.imag());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I wrote this short example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
complex<double> x;
x.real(1);
cout<<x.real()<<'\n';  

x.real()=0;
cout<<x.real()<<'\n';


x.real(2);
cout<<x.real()<<'\n';


double* y=&x.real();
cout<<*y<<'\n';
}
```

it compiles with -std=c++98 but not -std=c++11.
I tried -std=c++98 on emscripten but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `= 0` is exactly what it looks like - assignment to 0. I assume the `real()` method returns a reference to the real part of the complex number; the assignment sets that to 0. You say it doesn't compile with emscripten, but you don't even say what error message you get...

Comment: sorry, error: expression is not assignable

Comment: maybe a compiler setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::complex::real() returns a value not a reference.  This means you cannot assign a value to it and it can only appear on the right hand side of an expression.  In the C standards jargon that makes it an rvalue (as opposed to an lvalue which can appear on the left or right).

However, It looks like the code was originally trying to assign the real part to zero.

So, If that's what you intend then use this approach:

```
_matrix[ii][jj].real(0.0);
```

Older libraries may not support this* but it compiles fine with the latest clang++ I have here with this change (EDIT: using both std::complex and the template class you provided).

*http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1589.html